# How to change name of columns or rows in mdx query

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

I am new on Mondrian and OLAP. I try to change the names of columns. I haven't change yet. Here is my query:

```
WITH
SET ResponsibleSet AS {[Responsible].[Name].Members
MEMBER [Responsible].[RowSum] AS AGGREGATE(ResponsibleSet)
SELECT FILTER({[Balance].[Currency].Members}, not [Balance].[Currency].currentMember.Properties('Deleted')) ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY {ResponsibleSet, [Responsible].[RowSum]} ON ROWS FROM [Balance Cube] WHERE (Measures.[Sum])
```

RESULT:

```
|         | EXPENSE                     | INCOME                   |
|         | false                       | false                    |
|         | EUR     | TRY     | USD     | EUR    | TRY    | USD    |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| Joe     |      25 |      97 |      10 |     15 |    173 |     18 |
|         |      25 |      97 |      10 |     15 |    173 |     18 |
```

For example: I want to change 'EUR' column to 'EURO'. How can I change rename like this example with mdx query?
Also, the last row has not a name. How can I add a name to this row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure about Mondrian - but in (standard) MS mdx you could do something like this:

I've assumed the full name of euro in your cube is `[Balance].[Currency].[Currency].[Eur]` - you will need to replace as appropriate:

```
WITH 
  SET ResponsibleSet AS 
    {[Responsible].[Name].MEMBERS} 
  MEMBER [Responsible].[RowSum] AS 
    Aggregate(ResponsibleSet) 
  MEMBER [Balance].[Currency].[All].[Euro] AS 
    [Balance].[Currency].[Currency].[Eur] 
SELECT 
  {
    Except
    (
      Filter
      (
        {[Balance].[Currency].MEMBERS}
       ,(NOT 
          [Balance].[Currency].CurrentMember.Properties('Deleted'))
      )
     ,[Balance].[Currency].[Currency].[Eur]
    )
   ,[Balance].[Currency].[Currency].[Euro]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
      ResponsibleSet
     ,[Responsible].[RowSum]
    } ON ROWS
FROM [Balance Cube]
WHERE 
  Measures.[Sum];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 ways:

1. Add full name attribute in Balance.Currency dimension and display this instead of key
2. If you can set up different sources for Balance.Currency key and name - then MEMBER_KEY would be EUR but Balance.Currency will give you EURO
3. Translate EUR to EURO in UI/reporting tool

Of course for 1 & 2 you need to extend source table for currency dimension with currency name